# Merge Unused Space In Partitions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 2TB HDD that is split into multiple partitions (C:Main, D:Documents, E:Games, F:Media). My E partition is running out of space, but my D and F has plenty of space. Both partitions currently have files stored in them. I am wondering how can I move some of that unused space in D and F over to E?

I am running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.

Partitions must be seen as physical separations of your hard drive. You can't simply pick some free space there and put it elsewhere. You are only able to extend a partition from its end.

But there is hope.

If your partitions are in the order you mentioned in your question, you could check if F (media) fits in D (documents) and maybe renames it to Document and Media. It would allow you to delete F (media) and extend E (games) over the freed space.

Otherwise, you could backup F (media), delete it, re-size E (games) and create a new F (media) in the remaining space.

To figure out the actual order of your partitions, simply open the run prompt (**windows key + r**), type **diskmgmt.msc** and hit **enter**. From there you will have all the information you need to figure out the best course of action and all the tools required for deleting and resizing the partitions.

Always backup your important files when playing with partitions. It is a safe process, but we never know when an error may occur.